# Why is the Fuji capsule design philosophy not seen in other proposals?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, design-alternative, jaxa

[image]

[Fuji](https://www.mext.go.jp/b_menu/shingi/gijyutu/gijyutu2/059/shiryo/__icsFiles/afieldfile/2015/07/16/1359656_5.pdf) is my favorite unflown dead spacecraft proposal (narrowly beating out Dynasoar). I am well aware of *why* Fuji has its weird/unique design, but what I'm curious about is *why* it's unique. In my opinion, it's so brilliant I can't understand why nobody else is using it.

Let's review the components: it consists of a relatively standard architecture: service module, reentry module, mission module. It's a common design, seen in action by the highly successful Soyuz capsules & in the famous alt-history timeline, Eyes Turned Skyward, as Block III+ upgrades to the Apollo architecture.

But what makes it unique? First of all, the reentry module is very very flat. Supposedly, this is to allow for very low g-loading on reeentry, as it blurs the boundary between lifting body & blunt body. This is very advantageous for servicing a science station. One of the benefits of the shuttle was to allow such low-g-loaded reentries for g-sensitive experiments & science payloads.

Secondly, the mission module is very large compared to the reentry module. This makes a lot of sense to me: the narrow profile of the reentry module gives you very low internal volume for its diameter, so a large mission module is needed. But the benefit of this is apparent--a reentry module doesn't need to change much over the lifetime of a vehicle, but the on-orbit module can be upgraded & swapped out without compromising the safety afforded by a tried-and-true reentry module.

In short, I think the Fuji design is an excellent one for a long-serving crew capsule, and I question why I haven't seen a similar concept proposed anywhere else.

***As this is a rather subjective question, all answers are accepted! Please share your thoughts (as long as you've got a source to back your thinking up).*** The question is broad, and there is no "one right" answer.

Comment: Can you link to some references? I've never heard of it myself.

Comment: Good point. Most references are in Japanese, which I don't know, but I'll link the one English paper I've had sitting around. It's not great at all, but it's something. It doesn't mention the diameter, but I seem to remember it being the same diameter as the H-II, so 2.5 meters.

Comment: A paper in English: https://archive.ists.or.jp/upload_pdf/ISTS_2002-g-26.pdf

Comment: Thanks, David. I believe that's the same one that's now currently linked in the question, but if you find any other ones please feel free to edit my post. I'd love to see harder references on this thing (if only for my own personal appreciation) ;)

Comment: Given that the Fuji appears not even to have been *designed* until well after the Shuttle, there's been no current use case for it.  Soyuz systems were already tested and validated, and sufficed for ISS missions.  There haven't been any other manned missions since, so no justification for producing & testing the design.  Then SpaceX showed up and ruined everything for big government-based programs.

Comment: Note that Spacex's only near-term human spaceflight program is a big government-based program.

Comment: Also the linked paper is from 2002, before the last fatal Shuttle failure.

Comment: @OrganicMarble it's government - **funded** but not operated by the government the way NASA rockets were.

Comment: If the mission module stays in orbit and is reused, then it is more like the ISS or the Lunar Gateway, and it is indeed, much bigger and more complex than the reentry capsule. If not, then it is used up on every mission, which is wasteful. If you just make a larger reentry module, you get to reuse it.

Comment: Another article: seems credible but unsourced https://falsesteps.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/fuji-bringing-the-mountain-to-the-masses/

Comment: The paper linked in the question is about HTV-X, not Fuji?  @AntonHengst do you want to replace it with the one David Hammen linked to in his comment (internet archive required)?